# Why does my SharePoint website sitemap get rolled back?

Tags: sharepoint, sitemap, office365, sharepoint-online

I build an Office 365 SharePoint website and got a default sitemap from it. The Sitemap was not updated according to the pages I added to the website, hence I made changes to the sitemap. But every time I make the changes to the sitemap, it gets rolled back to the initial default sitemap, as it was once when the website was created. Please help, if you know how to get it updated without it being rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a default Sitemap. So first you need to find out, how it was created in the first place. Do you have any further details?

That your manual changes are not persistent might relate to this generation process - most probably there is a timerjob gathering the information and writing the sitemap file (and overwriting your changes) ...

Comment: There is always a sitemap for sample websites created in the Office 365 sharepoint website.Now if a new website is created, it automatically creates the sitemap for it taking the default value of the sample website.I try to change the content according to the links from the new website but in vain as it gets all rolled back. I have no idea about the timerjob so please can you explain where you found the timerjob thing on it?